# How do I Find/Replace 'Project' in MS Money in bulk? Should I export to database, edit and re import? If so how?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-money

MS Money has Find/Replace for Payee, Category, Memo and Number but not Project. How can I replace Project with some new text?

Answer (score 0):

Money is discontinued since 2009 and it never had an option to find-replace
in projects.
In 2010 Microsoft released the replacement product
Microsoft Money Plus Sunset, which has since also become defunct.

One product that could be useful for editing is
[sunriise](https://sunriise.sourceforge.net/) :

> sunriise goal is to provide read/write support for Microsoft Money *.mny file.

Sunriise is an old project dating from 2011 and written in Java.
Take a backup of your Money files before using it (if you manage to).

However, for me your best bet is to export the data from Money
and move to another product (I can't recommend any).

Money seems to be able to export its data to CSV format which can be used
in Excel and many other products, or export to QIF format which is used
in Quicken. I suggest to export the data and import it to whichever
product you choose that can accept the Money export file.